# Parsing error: in Conditional raster calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, raster-calculator, conditional, error-000989

I was trying to calculate Soil types based on the FAO's guidline using the **Con** tool in **raster calculation** with ArcGIS 10.3. from three layers (silt, clay & sand). But, I got an error saying:

> Python syntax error:Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax line1

I have put the code below. What is wrong with it?

```
OutRas = Con(("siltwtdavg" + 1.5*"claywtdavg")<15,1, Con(( "siltwtdavg"+ 1.5*"claywtdavg" >= 15) & (silt + 2*"claywtdavg" < 30),2, Con(("claywtdavg" >= 7 & "claywtdavg"< 20) & ("sand_av" > 52) & (("siltwtdavg" + 2*"claywtdavg") >= 30) | ("claywtdavg" < 7 & "siltwtdavg" < 50 & ("siltwtdavg"+2*"claywtdavg")>=30), 3, Con(("claywtdavg" >= 7 & "claywtdavg" < 27) & ("siltwtdavg" >= 28 & "siltwtdavg" < 50) & ("sand_av" <= 52),4, Con(("siltwtdavg" >= 50 & ("claywtdavg" >= 12 && "claywtdavg" < 27)) | (("siltwtdavg" >= 50 & "siltwtdavg" < 80) & "claywtdavg" < 12),5, Con("siltwtdavg" >= 80 & "claywtdavg" < 12, 6, Con(("claywtdavg" >= 20 && "claywtdavg" < 35) && ("siltwtdavg" < 28) && ("sand_av" > 45), 7, Con(("claywtdavg" >= 27 && "claywtdavg" < 40) && ("sand_av" > 20 && "sand_av" <= 45), 8, Con(("claywtdavg" >= 27 && "claywtdavg" < 40) && ("sand_av"  <= 20), 9, Con("claywtdavg" >= 35 && "sand_av" > 45), 10, Con("claywtdavg" >= 40 && "siltwtdavg" >= 40), 11, 12 )))))))))))
```

Comment: To start with, you have two extra parentheses at the end of the code. It takes patience to parse through such a long con statement. I advise you to use an illustrated editor that highlights corresponding open and closed parentheses to catch any syntax error. Notepad++ is one of the good ones.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you have two extra parentheses at the end of the code. It takes patience to parse through such a long con statement. I advise you to use an illustrated editor that highlights corresponding open and closed parentheses to catch any syntax error. Notepad++ is one of the good ones.